# Error accessing a packaged class, 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I know this question has been asked countless times on SO, but mine is just weird.

I have a package called `critters` for the characters in my game.

Of all the classes in this package, one (`ACustomSocket`) encountered 1046 error when I declare it in my code. `Dog` is in the same package but does not get the error.

```
package{
  import critters.*;
  // all necessary imports follow

  public class GameGUI extends MovieClip {
    ...
    private var socket:ACustomSocket;
    private var dog:Dog;
    ...
  }
}
```

Why is there such a difference?
Here's how ACustomSocket is declared.

```
package critters {

    import flash.errors.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.Socket;

    class ACustomSocket extends Socket {
        private var response:String;
        public function ACustomSocket(host:String = null, port:uint = 0) {
           ....
        }        
    }
}
```

And here Dog.

```
package critters {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Dog extends MovieClip {

        // Initialization:
        public function Dog() {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: comment out as much as you can until it works, then keep commenting stuff back in until it works. this will track down where the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Well make your class `ACustomSocket` **Public** so other package can use it :

```
public class ACustomSocket extends Socket {...}
```